# Extract co-linear columns name - R

Tags: r

Based on the answer for this [question and its script](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212667/how-do-i-find-co-linear-variables-in-r), how can I print to the console the co-linear columns names?

Script:

```
library(corrplot)
library(caret)

x <- seq(0, 100, 1)
# colinear with x
y <- x + 2.3 
# almost colinear with x / some small gaussian noise 
z <- x + rnorm(mean = 0, sd = 5, n = 101)
# uncorrrelated gaussian 
w <- rnorm(mean = 0, sd = 1, n = 101)
a <- z+seq(101, 200, 1)/.33 + rnorm(mean = 0, sd = 5, n = 1001)
b <- a -2.3

# this frame is made to exemplify the procedure
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, w = w, a=a, b=b)

corrplot(cor(df))
#drop perfectly multicollinear variables
constant<-rep(1,nrow(df))
tmp<-lm(constant ~ ., data=df)
to_keep<-tmp$coefficients[!is.na(tmp$coefficients)]
to_keep<-names(to_keep[-which(names(to_keep) == "(Intercept)")])
df_result<-df[to_keep]
corrplot(cor(df_result))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the variables not included in `to_keep`. Based off how `to_keep` is defined, you can write `to_drop <- tmp$coefficients[is.na(tmp$coefficients)]` to get the coefficients with `NA` values (meaning there are no estimates for the corresponding variables because they are collinear with others). Then, to print the names of those coefficients, you can simply do `print(names(to_drop))`.

However, keep in mind that: 1. this will only drop perfectly collinear variables in a hacky way and 2. the way this method decides which variables out of a set of perfectly collinear variables to drop is rather arbitrary (it will depend on the other of variables in your data).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it will remove perfect correlations.  Is there a no "hacky way" to write it?